# Freeswitch Originate to SIP endpoint with Password

Tags: freeswitch

Looking to originate a call from Freeswitch to an external SIP phone using originate.

In the Freeswitch docs I can see this being done as "originate sofia/example/300@foo.com 8600" however can not see any information on how to set the password.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
originate [sip_auth_username='xxxxxxx',sip_auth_password='xxxxxxxx']sofia/external/111111@example.com &park()
```

or

```
<action application="bridge" data="[sip_auth_username='user',sip_auth_password='xxxxxx']user/1000@default"/>
```

Comment: A quick explanation of code would make for a better answer.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, that is what I was looking for.